# Становление объекта после отпускания пальцем карты

Tags: unity3d

Я делаю игру - головоломку. Персонажу надо от одного острова добраться через воду до пляжа. Для этого нужно поставить надувные круги так, чтобы персонаж от них отпрыгивал и не упал в воду. у каждого круга свои способности. Например от обычного круга  персонаж отскакивает вперед от другого в бок от третьего еще какая то способность. Эти круги ставит человек с помощью карт(как в любой карточной игре. Белый квадрат на картинке в серой рамочке пока что и есть эта карта). Я хочу чтобы человек делал это пальцем и когда палец человек отпускает, то на месте карты появляется этот круг. Как это сделать? Всем заранее спасибо)[image]

Comment: Вот док https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html Узнавайте место касания и меняйте позицию карты к позиции касания, когда отпустит, на последней кординате создайте объект, все

Comment: @Gilly а если у меня через IDragHandler движение карты. И еще как взять позицию после последнего касания

Comment: честно, с касаниями не работал, но думаю все схоже как и с мышкой. Записывайте в какуе нибудь переменную эти данные и  последние данные будут последними) Думаю это нужно делать в апдейте

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно обрабатывать касания.
В методе `Update` проверять наличие касаний, их фазу и позицию. Все это есть в классе `Touch`.

```
private void Update(){
    if(Input.touchCount > 0){ //Проверка наличия касаний
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // Получить касания
        Vector2 pos = touch.position; // Получить позицию в пикселях
        switch (touch.phase) // проверить фазу
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began: //нажатие
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved: // движение
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended: // отпуск
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Позицию в пикселях можно перевести в мировые координаты с помощью `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint();`